# I want to access data in a Method(Test) under the Class(Profile) using Ajax, jQuery and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to access data by "Test" method under the "Profile" class. But data does not come on "Test" method. I'm using jquery, ajax and CodeIgniter. Can anyone help me ?

jQuery and Ajax functionality.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function hideResponse(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#response").slideUp("slow", function(){});
        }, 2000); 
    }

    $("#response").hide();

    $(function(){
        $("#list .sections").sortable({ opacity: 0.5, cursor: 'move', update: function(){
            var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Profile/Test',  //'Profile' class and 'Test' method.
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#response").html(response);
                    $("#response").slideDown('slow');
                    hideResponse();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Fail');
                }
            });
        } });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here "Test" method under the "Profile" class.

```
public function Test()
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['data']))
    {
        $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

        parse_str( $data, $str );

        print_r($str);  // here data does not come
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI your `hideResponse()` function is out of scope of where you're calling it as you have two DOMReady handlers. Join them in to one

Comment: Still same, does not work. Can you give me your solution ?

Comment: I don't have a solution as I don't know Codeigniter I'm afraid. Just letting you know that your JS code would also have been a problem.

Comment: It's ok. But JS code does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have made the Profile class in the controller file(Controller folder): Profile.php(CI 3) and for profile.php( CI 2 )

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Profile extends CI_Controller {
 public function Test()
     {
          // your code
        }
}
```

Then in the ajax call:

```
url: '<?php echo base_url("profile/test"); ?>',  
//'Profile' class and 'Test' method.
```

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it is not solution for this question. I already solved this problem.